# Whats the maximum number of adhoc SAS tokens supported on a blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Whats the maximum number of adhoc SAS token supported on a blob?

For example, I have a file which is stored in azure blob container. There are 4000+ clients. These clients will request this file. For each request, I will generate an adhoc SAS token uri for the file. Which means that 4000+ adhoc SAS token URIs.

So is there any limit on number of adhoc SAS tokens a blob supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're no limitation for adhoc SAS token for a blob.

But you don't need to create a sastoken for each client, it can be re-used.